# Django Hive connectivity

Tags: python, django, hive, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'sampletest',
        'OPTIONS': {
           'driver': '/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/64/libclouderahiveodbc64.so',
           'dsn': 'Hive1',
           'host_is_server': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Above is the Django settings for the connectivity with the Hive database; Here I am facing an issue when I run the project which is given below:

```
django.db.utils.Error: ('HY000', u"[HY000] [Cloudera][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:7 character '@' not supported here\nline 1:8 character '@' not supported here (80) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

The query where it is occurring is actually a standard query

```
"SELECT @@TRANCOUNT"
```

which is triggered by Django while connectivity

Please suggest solution. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, Django is not compatible with Hive. The database engine you're using, `django-pyodbc-azure`, is for SQL Server only. Django supports PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite and Oracle out of the box. SQL Server is supported through third party engines such as `django-pyodbc-azure`. I don't know of any other currently supported engines (MongoDB used to have an engine, but hasn't been maintained).

That said, you can probably use one of the above engines for Django's `default` setting and ORM interactions, and use `pyodbc` directly to connect to Hive at the Python level; I do something similar, where I use PostgreSQL for Django, and an unsupported database for data. Good luck!